# How do I substitute InAppBrowser for ChildBrowser in PhoneGap 2.3.0 using Xcode?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am following [this adobe tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/phonegap-apps-powered-by-developercom.html) about setting up a remote db connection using database.com. He uses ChildBrowser which I couldn't get working on my version of PG. So I updated PG to 2.3.0 and I find there's this new cool thing, the InAppBrowser. The basic examples of IAB I can get working just fine, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it in the above tutorial. Any help is appreciated. My Git Repo is [here](https://github.com/mcemond/test2013). Thanks for reading! Mike

Answer (score 0):

So, I realize my question is a little broad. At this point cordova 2.3.0 and InAppBrowser are a little too new for there to be a lot of documentation out there so basically what I did was use an older version of cordova in order to have the tutorial match my process.

The tutorial linked above is Andrew Trice's and they responded to me that they intend to write an update to the tutorial using IAB. The version of Cordova that he is using as far as I can tell is 1.7.0. I had been using 1.4.1 prior on another machine so 1.7.0's dmg file could be installed straight from the finder and the two versions seem to be autonomous within xcode. I was creating a brand new project so I was able to ignore the somewhat lengthy cordova upgrade instructions. All source files were copied over from the tutorial git repo. And the childbrowser was installed using the instructions here: [Ryan Stewart ChildBrower](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/) . I found this set of instructions to be the best I'd found. The only change is the External Hosts that you need are *.database.com and *.salesforce.com.

Hope that helps others in the same bind.

Mike

Edit: Use the child browser plugin for iOS not iPhone. And add a "Telephone" field to your db table.