# phonegap FBConnect Plugins some steps troubles

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, fbconnect

I started developing the iphone app using phonegap >>

I have used phonegap before for android app>and also fbconnect for android but for ios I am not able to configure it>> I gone through many tutorials and Questions from stackoverflow>

I am following this tutorial
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/

> > and every things goes right but the steps 11 to 14 >> and last ios URL SCHEME

thats are the steps which are confusing me aND I AM UNABLE TO COMPLETE THat steps>>
and if I compile without thats steps>>
its giving the following error>>

> error: Cordova/CDV.h: No such file or directory

@Geeniewanted :: this is the screen 
[image]

Comment: have you tried using the new inappbrowser in cordova 2.3.0 for facebook login?

Comment: no>> but i studied that 1.4.1 have more support and flexibility>> |
if 2.3.0 is more suitable than suggest me a usefull tutorial link where i can follow foe FB connect >

Comment: try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345178/how-do-i-substitute-inappbrowser-for-childbrowser-in-phonegap-2-3-0-using-xcode

Comment: i have mac with snowleopard>> and xcode version 3.2.6>
for phonegap 2.3.0 i need to upgrade the mac>> which is not applicable now >> and xcode version also lower here>>

Answer (score 0):

For 11. If you click on the top-level '`phonegapFacebookApplication`' in your project navigator (with the blue x-code project icon to it's left), that should show you all the project settings on the main center window. There you will find a tab that says "`Build Phases`", and within that, you'll find an option to add Link binaries with Libraries. @Geeniewanted has nicely written out a solution to that above.

I should warn you though that if you're using the lastest PhoneGap Build, or Cordova, you'll notice that there isn't a Cordova.plist anymore. That is because with PhoneGap 2.3.0 they've changed that to the '`config.xml`'. And so you'll have to add your plug-ins to there.

I would recommend that you follow the video tutorial from Facebook-Dev to set up your Facebook iOS SDK within x-code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/#project

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following link to use the childbrowser plugin and facebook
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88#comment-1544

it's possible to update this to the new inappbrowser

Comment: i have used it>> its look gud but its >> but its workig its some confusing
that i have to retrieve the friend list of the active login user>
that is not working for me using facebook SDK 
any idea on it will be appreciated :